# Derivation of Jones-polynomial from HOMFLY-polynomial

Tags: polynomials, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I came across something seemingly trivial, but I don't know why this mistake happens.

We have the HOMFLY-polynomial $P(L)\in\mathbb{Z}[l^{\pm1},m^{\pm1}]$ for oriented links $L$, which satisfies:

1) Normalization: $P(unknot)=1$

2) Skein-relation: $lP(L_{+})+l^{-1}P(L{-})=-mP(L_{0})$

for $L_{+,-,0}$ a knot diagram differing in one crossing by over-/under-/no crossing.
(Lickorish-Millet-version)

On the other hand, we have the Jones-polynomial $V(L)\in\Bbb{Z}[t^{\pm1/2}]$ with similar properties:

1) Normalization: $V(unknot)=1$

2) Skein-relation: $t^{-1}V(L_{+})-tV(L{-})=(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})V(L_{0})$

Now, as the HOMFLY-polynomial is a generalization of the Jones-polynomial, we can (according to my class and Wikipedia) do the following substitution:

$$V(t)=P(l=t^{-1},m=t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})$$

When I try to substitute this directly in the HOMFLY Skein-relation, I end up with the wrong sign in front of the $tV(L_{-})$ in the JONES Skein-relation.

Can anybody tell me, whether I have done a stupid Algebra mistake, or have overlooked something that flips the sign during the substitution?

Much obliged

Nik

Comment: Btw is anyone can tell me tips on how to make this question more readable, thanks to you too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (unfortunately) a number of conventions for the HOMFLY-PT polynomial.  The cleanest version is that $P(L)\in\mathbb Z[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1}]$ with $P(\mathrm{unknot}) = 1$ and the skein relation
$$ xP(L_+) + yP(L_-) + zP(L_0) = 0.$$
This is a homogeneous polynomial in three variables.  By making some choice of projectivization, this can be reduced to a two-variable polynomial.  Some common ones are
\begin{align*}
\alpha P(L_+) - \alpha^{-1} P(L_-) - z P(L_0) &= 0 \\
\ell P(L_+) + \ell^{-1} P(L_-) +m P(L_0) &= 0
\end{align*}
(and all three versions show up in [the original HOMFLY paper](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~egorskiy/MAT280-s18/HOMFLY.pdf)!  The $x,y,z$ parameterization is the Main Theorem, the $\ell,\ell^{-1},m$ parameterization is the Lickorish and Millet approach, and the $\alpha,-\alpha^{-1},-z$ parameterization is the Ocneanu approach after a slight substitution.)

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOMFLY_polynomial) shows how to get the Jones polynomial from $P(\alpha,z)$, but you have $P(\ell,m)$.  Let's arrange the HOMFLY and Jones polynomials against each other to see the equations we need to solve:
\begin{align*}
\ell P(L_+) + \ell^{-1} P(L_-) &= -m P(L_0) \\
t^{-1}V(L_+) - t V(L_-) &= (t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}) V(L_0).
\end{align*}
On the face of it, it seems impossible that simultaneously both $\ell=t^{-1}$ and $\ell^{-1}=-t$ are true!  However, we are allowed to scale equations by a nonzero constant $c$:
\begin{align*}
\ell P(L_+) + \ell^{-1} P(L_-) &= -m P(L_0) \\
ct^{-1}V(L_+) - ct V(L_-) &= c(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}) V(L_0).
\end{align*}
This gives the system of equations
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\ell=ct^{-1}\\
\ell^{-1}=-ct\\
-m=c(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}).
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Since I'm more in the business of talking about the knot theory than solving equations by hand, I asked Mathematica for the answer:

```
In[33]:= Solve[l==c t^-1 && l^-1==-c t && -m==c(t^(1/2)-t^(-1/2)), {c,l,m}]
Out[33]= {{c->I,l->I/t,m->-((I (-1+t))/Sqrt[t])},
          {c->-I,l->-(I/t),m->(I (-1+t))/Sqrt[t]}}
```

This says we may make either of the two substitutions given by the $\pm$'s:
\begin{align*}
\ell &= \pm it^{-1} \\
m &= \mp i(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}),
\end{align*}
and the result is the skein relation for the Jones polynomial, but scaled by a factor of $\pm i$.

Comment: Wow, this makes so much sense. Thank you very much!

When you mentioned the Wikipedia articles, I went back to check again, and it turns out, the German page doesn't have the same amount of information as the English one. The part about the different skein-relations is missing! :'D